# What is GHC.Exts, and how were its contents chosen?

Tags: haskell

The [GHC.Exts](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.2/GHC-Exts.html) module in the Haskell standard library claims that it

> is the Approved Way to get at GHC-specific extensions.

If that's true, it explains the inclusion of implementation-specific constants like [the constant representing the maximum size of a tuple](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.2/GHC-Exts.html#g:2) and (presumably) non-portable [debugging functions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.2/GHC-Exts.html#g:6).

However, it doesn't explain why [`sortWith`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.2/GHC-Exts.html#v:sortWith) is in this module. [Its implementation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.2/src/GHC-Exts.html#sortWith) looks like normal, portable Haskell to me.
I'd expect to see it in, e.g., Data.List and Data.Sequence.

It seems I misunderstand what GHC.Exts is, I don't understand the underlying logic behind its collection of exports, or there's some historical reason it exports a hodgepodge of things.

So, **what is GHC.Exts for**? and **why does it export such a weird mixture of stuff**?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I *think* the *main* thing `GHC.Exts` is for is exporting everything GHC-internal which users might want to import, so that the developers don't have to worry about reorganizing the other internal modules. As a side effect of this, it has also become the official path for importing GHC-specific extension stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those functions and the [`Down`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:Down) newtype are for a syntactic extension: [Generalised (SQL-Like) List Comprehensions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.2/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#generalised-list-comprehensions), enabled with `-XTransformListComp`.

This extension introduces keywords that correspond to those functions:

> There are three new keywords: `group`, `by`, and `using`. (The function
>   `sortWith` is not a keyword; it is an ordinary function that is exported
>   by [`GHC.Exts`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.2/GHC-Exts.html).)

Those functions are working on lists, but they really belong to an extension (and [`GHC.Exts`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.2/GHC-Exts.html) is the extensions' home).

And the reason [`GHC.Exts`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.2/GHC-Exts.html) exports a varied mixture of stuff is because there are a varied mixture of extensions.

If you'd like to see more, see the [user guide page](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.2/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#generalised-list-comprehensions) -- and for even more, the [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/list-comp/) for it by Phil Wadler and Simon Peyton Jones. It's actually quite exciting imo, here's an example from the user guide page:

I truncated it, but you can say stuff like:

```
[ .. | (name, dept, salary) <- employees
, then group by dept
, then sortWith by (sum salary)
, then take 5 ]
```

And as another example:

```
output = [x| y <- [1..5], x <- "hello"
, then group using inits]
```

Yields:

```
["","h","he","hel","hell","hello","helloh","hellohe","hellohel","hellohell","hellohello","hellohelloh",...]
```

Comment: Ah, I see. So, just to make sure I understand:  `-XTransformListComp` enables a GHC extension. That extension is not implemented in Haskell, except for a couple pieces. The pure-Haskell pieces live in GHC.Exts, along with pieces of other extensions that, like `sortWith`, don't live in their own module.

Comment: @mambocab Yup, you got it! In `GHC.Exts`, after all the primitives it's all extensions to either give an interface (like with `XOverloadedLists`), or to provide functionality without hard-coding too much on the extension (like in here). It's pretty dangerous and there's really no need for it, so might as-well make the extension *just* call regular functions. And the `GHC.Exts` would be the place to put them, of course). Except for the primitives, everything there isn't really "vanilla" Haskell, so to speak.

Comment: I think the primitives are there too because there's freedom on the compilers on how to implement them (by the specification), so while their existence is a rigid part of Haskell, their implementation isn't, and here it's specific to how GHC chose to implement them.

Comment: Only moderately stable primitives make it into `GHC.Exts`. There are some experimental things in `GHC.Prim`, etc.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai the type is `sortWith :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]`, so presumably you'd use tuples to do a multi-property sort: `sortWith (\x -> (prop1 x, prop2 x, prop3 x, …)) xs`. Checking the implementation, it's `sortWith f = sortBy (\x y -> compare (f x) (f y))`, so that's the way to do it.